# Query regarding Cassandra java BoundStatement with multiple attributes

Tags: java, rest, cassandra

I'm trying to fetch records from Cassandra using BoundStatement's bind method and then doing session.execute on that.
Suppose the json looks like this as shown below

```
{
id:1,
name:abc,
.
.
.
}
```

Here,if I want to query using multiple columns (id=1 and name=abc),I'm able to fetch the records successfully.

However, my json looks something like this:

```
{
id:1
name:["abc","xyz"]
.
.
.
}
```

In the database, it gets saved in two different rows(as there are list of values associated with the name attribute)

The problem is how can I fetch the records from the database?

P.S.:id and name are compound partition key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` and `name` are part of a compound partition key you will always need to search by both of them. So you can take your JSON and fan out the name list into a few select queries or use an `IN`.

**Recommended Solution**

Use two different SELECT queries at the same time then aggregate the results this allows each SELECT to hit the best node assuming you are using TokenAware.

I use RxJava to spread out to many requests then merge them back to a list of rows.

```
public class CassandraService {
  //...

  public void run() {

    String id = "1";
    List<String> names = ['abc','xyz'];


    PreparedStatement selectStmt = session.prepare("SELECT id, name, value FROM table WHERE id=? AND name=?;");
    List statements = new ArrayList<Statement>();

    for(String name : names) {
      statements.add(selectStmt.bind(id,name));
    }

    Observable<Row> rows = execute(statements);

    //Do work with rows.
  }


  public Observable<ResultSet> executeAndReturnResultSet(Statement statement) {
    return Observable.from(session.executeAsync(statement));
  }


  public Observable<Row> execute(List<Statement> statements) {
    List<Observable<ResultSet>> resultSets = Lists.transform(statements, this::executeAndReturnResultSet);
    return Observable.merge(resultSets).flatMap(Observable::from);
  }
}
```

**Alternative**

Otherwise you could use `IN` like the following CQL:

```
SELECT * FROM multi_partition_key WHERE id='1' AND name IN ('abc','xyz');
```

For binding to a prepared statement in the Java Driver.

```
String id = "1";
List<String> names = ['abc','xyz'];

PreparedStatement sel = session.prepare("SELECT id, name, value FROM table WHERE id=? AND name IN ?;");
session.execute(sel.bind(id,name));
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your prompt response. I searched around the internet and found that using IN clause will degrade the performance.

Comment: Is there any other alternative that we can make use of?

Comment: yes in my answer my perferred way is to send two select statements at once.

Comment: If you need a Java example of that as well let me know